# How to fix 'Not only selected items go to collection' in C#

Tags: c#

Im currently doing a formular, in which are two datagrids. In one are list of components in main filter, in the second the user choose which filters he wants to see and use. But, he can also choose he made mistake and send back one or more items to original list of components.

There is a problem. When he check one or more items ( I make custom datagrid, which allow me select more items and give it into list. ), not only selected items send to original list of components, but also unselected items dissapear.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Move list of selected components to selected component-list
        /// </summary>
        private void DoMoveComponentsToList()
        {
            ObservableCollection<EComponentsForMainFilter> comps = JoinLists(_selectedFilteredComponents, _selectedComponents);
            ComponentsOutOfSelectedComponentListFiltered = new ObservableCollection<EComponentsForMainFilter>();
            for (int i = comps.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ComponentsOutOfSelectedComponentListFiltered.Remove(comps[i]);
                CollectionOfComponents.Add(comps[i]);
            }
            //NotifyPropertyChanged("ComponentsOutOfSelectedComponentListFiltered");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CollectionOfComponents");
        }
        ///// <summary>
        ///// Move list of selected components out of selected component-list
        ///// </summary>
        private void DoMoveComponentsFromList()
        {
            ObservableCollection<EComponentsForMainFilter> comps = SubtractLists(_selectedComponents, _selectedFilteredComponents);
            ComponentsOutOfSelectedComponentListFiltered = new ObservableCollection<EComponentsForMainFilter>();
            for (int i = comps.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ComponentsOutOfSelectedComponentListFiltered.Add(comps[i]);
                CollectionOfComponents.Remove(comps[i]);
            }          
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ComponentsOutOfSelectedComponentListFiltered");
            //NotifyPropertyChanged("CollectionOfComponents");
        }
```

In this code i add checked components from original collection to user selected collection or checked components from user collection to original collection.

I expect the output send to original collection only selected items if he made a mistake, not selected and unselected.

Comment: what are `_selectedFilteredComponents` and `_selectedComponents` My guess is that your multi-selection doesn't do what you assume it does. did you have a look at it with a debugger?

Comment: @FalcoGer _selectedComponents = selected items from original datagrid in which i store list of components, _selectedFilteredComponents = this are selected items made by user from original collection of components :) sorry for my bad english

Comment: With the given code it's hard to say but my guess is that you only should do `ComponentsOutOfSelectedComponentListFiltered = new Observable... ` if it is null

Comment: How do you fetch those? are they properties? Have a look at them in the debugger and see if your problem lies there.

Comment: @FalcoGer In debugger it seems all ok. But when the user made a mistake a want send back items which he choose to the original collection, so not only selected items go back, but also unselected. So I dont really know where is the problem :/ In debugger there are only two selected items if he choose two.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your Control here:

```
ComponentsOutOfSelectedComponentListFiltered = new ObservableCollection<EComponentsForMainFilter>();
```

Afterwards it is of course empty.
It seems like you forgot to change it to `CollectionOfComponents = new [...]` when you copied the other bit of code.
I recommend to use some form of `Clear()` function instead of creating a new object. It is more clear what you mean with your code, and it uses less resources than to allocate new memory, etc.
Alternatively you could create a generic move function to move a `Component` from one `ObservableCollection` to another that handles removing and adding and then only iterate through the list of selected components.

Comment: Thanks, I try that :)

Comment: @Azgraloth so, was that it?

Comment: Well. I deleted all this code. My bussiness manager told me that users want only one grid, they want minimum clicks. So they only choose selected items and click ok. So it easier my work.

Comment: @Azgraloth looks like you should've gone with checkboxes to begin with :3